# Local variables still cause memory leak when the thread wait()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have met a memory leak in the following code:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            if(!isRunning) {
                break;
            }
            ThreadHandler handler = threadHandlerRef.get();
            if(handler == null) {
                break;
            }

            handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 1, this));

            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The memory leak is like below:

```
In com.****.****:4.2.10:6796.
* com.****.****.SmartConfigMainActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT com.****.****..NetworkDetector$DThread.<Java Local>
* references android.os.Message.obj
* references com.****.****.$3.a
* references com.****.****.mCommonBindView
* references com.****.****.CommonBindView.mContext
* leaks com.****.****. instance
```

The thread, as the gc root, holding the local varaiables such as Message. So, the wait() call, from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719054/what-does-a-thread-do-after-calling-wait-in-java):

1. tells the currently executing thread go to sleep (not use any cpu).
2. releases the lock so other threads can wake up and take the lock.

Seems wait() also result in holding the local variables. I did not realize this before. Where these local variables? Is it still in the "VM Stack"? Is there more tutorial about this?

=================UPDATE=======================

The SmartConfigMainActivity does not have any relations with the NetworkDetector. I think the Message is re-used in the Looper, which cuased this memory-leak. But I cannot control this re-use behaviour of android.
As I see, jvm should save the local variable to prevent it from gc because when wait() returns, it should come back to the origin state and use these variables. But I did not see any tutorial about this

Comment: `wait` does not hot on to local variables; being in the method that declares the local variable holds on to the local variable! You only have one local variable in your method, `handler`. It's not really clear what you are asking here (asking for an external resource like a tutorial is off-topic on SO). You have *-out all the information your "memory leak" do we can't make sense of it. Staying in a method indefinitely after you're done is generally just not a very good idea.

Comment: Yes, the run() has some serious defects, such as isRunning is not volatile and should return/break when interrupted from wait().  I am just curious about thread holding local variables when wait() is called. This may cause memory leak if not handled properly.